# vba loop through column and if certain value then increment

Tags: excel, vba, range, increment

I have a column C filled with empty cells or cells that contain value "OK". I need that every cell which contains text "OK" will be change to incremented value 1,2,3 etc. total 2642 cells

```
   C

- 1 [empty]
- 2 [empty]
- 3 [OK]
- 4 [empty]
- 5 [OK]
- 6 [empty]
```

Need to look like:
       C

```
- 1 [empty]
- 2 [empty]
- 3 [1]
- 4 [empty]
- 5 [2]
- 6 [empty]
```

Basically i need to autoincrement but when filter data autoincrement doesn't work

Code i use autoincrements all values by not display value on the the cell that contain word "OK" like this:

```
   C

- 1 [1]
- 2 [2]
- 3 [empty]
- 4 [4]
- 5 [empty]
- 6 [6]
```

Code:

```
    Sub Macro1()
    mynumber = 1
    Dim r As Range, cell As Range
    Set r = Range(Range("C1"), Range("C2642").End(xlDown))
    For Each cell In r
      If cell.Value = OK Then cell.Value = mynumber
       mynumber = mynumber + 1
    Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is close but the problem you are having is that your cell value is checking `OK` thinking it is a variable.  To avoid this the first thing you want to do is put `Option Explicit` at the top of each module to tell you when you haven't declared variables.

Now all you need to do is make 'OK' a string like `"OK"`.  You also need to increment your number inside the `If` statement otherwise it'll keep incrementing even when you don't want it to.

Edit: you can also your range a bit more simply by just defining the cells in the `Range` method like in this code.  Its not as flexible as using `End` but if you have a fixed range will do the trick.

Try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    Dim r As Range, cell As Range, mynumber As Long

    Set r = Range("C1:C2642")

    mynumber = 1
    For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value = "OK" Then
            cell.Value = mynumber
            mynumber = mynumber + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a macro:

1. Change to R1C1 reference style (*File* tab->*Options*->*Calculation*->*R1C1 reference style*
2. Select the full column
3. Replace dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>)
4. Replace all `OK` with `=MAX(R1C1:R[-1]C)+1`
5. If you wish, copy and paste special the values
6. Uncheck R1C1 reference style

Alternatively, you can also do this without R1C1 style by using an Autofilter:

1. Apply an AutoFilter to your column (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>)
2. Filter for `OK`
3. Select all filtered `OK`s
4. Enter the following formula: `=MAX($A$1:$A2)+1` - enter it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>. You need to slightly adjust the formula - replace `$A$1` with the first row your data start (or the header row) - and `$A2` with *the cell above your active cell* - even if it's hidden!
5. Remove the AutoFilter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>) and copy/paste special values if you wish